# How to customize syntax highlight in PL\SQL Developer to mark aliases?

Tags: editor, customization, alias, plsqldeveloper

I found myself scanning through long and complicated *selects* often searching for the right alias.
Is there a way to highlight them all?
For example 'strings' have a special style.

How do I set custom style for aliases like "column_name"?

Answer (score 0):

There is an official solution for this very Stack Overflow question! (Thats how I got here... :) )

This can be found in SQL Ddeveloper:
*Preferences... / Code Editor / PL/SQL Syntax Colors / PL/SQL Custom Syntax Rules*

So now we can set the color for "PlSqlColTabAlases" (Sic!) in the Syntax Colors list. (Default is light brown.)

```
/**
 * The list of syntax highlighting rules:
   https://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2018/10/10/custom-syntax-coloring/
 * In-depth description of the Arbori language:
   https://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/arbori-the-missing-manuals/  
**/
 
/**
 * Highlighting all the column and table aliases
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193403/how-to-customize-syntax-highlight-in-pl-sql-developer-to-mark-aliases 
 */
PlSqlColTabAlases:                          -- 
   [node) c_alias                           -- Search all the nodes in the parse tree which are column aliases
 | [node) identifier                        -- Or nodes with identifier payload,  
    & [node-1) query_table_expression   -- which younger siblings are labeled with table names
->                                          -- The semantic action symbol (to trigger syntax highlighting).
;                                           -- End of the rule
```